# Importing a sample from an already imported library in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

In android studios, I have successfully imported a library called ChatKit(https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit). The creators of the library were kind enough to include a fully working sample within the library. Instead of recreating the process I want to import the sample from the library into my project but android studios is not allowing me to do so.

In my main activity, I can add :

```
import com.stfalcon.chatkit.dialogs.DialogsList;
```

But when cannot add:

```
import com.stfalcon.chatkit.sample.ChatSamplesListAdapter;
```

So I'm curious what other people have done to import a sample from an already imported library.

Thank you.

Comment: The sample is probably not included in the Maven artifact.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, can you suggest a path I can take to try progressing this issue? thank you

Comment: The easiest way is to copy the files from the sample directly into your own project.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> import com.stfalcon.chatkit.sample.ChatSamplesListAdapter;

It happens because this class is not included in the library.
It is a [sample file](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/stfalcon/chatkit/sample/ChatSamplesListAdapter.java) used as sample.

As you can see it is just a simple `RecyclerView.Adapter` then you can copy it in your project or you can use a own adapter.